# Measure mobile app downloads using Mixpanel

Tags: android, ios, google-play, analytics, mixpanel

I want to measure the number of downloads of my app using Mixpanel in order to use this measurement as a event in the Mixpanel dashboard.

The app is available in Android and iOS. 
Being Mixpanel a tool to measure and create funnels, there should be a way to get the information about downloads from Google Play Store and App Store, but I have read the docs and I didn´t find any helpful about it.

How can I watch the app downloads from Mixpanel?

Comment: no in-app tool can tell you about downloads, because the app may never be opened.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I was guessing if Mixpanel could get this info from the stores in some way, since it is a main magnitude in the marketing funnel

Comment: yes. in the funnels of people who actually use your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting support@mixpanel.com, they kindly answered my question. I paste here the response in order to help those with the same doubt:

> Tracking mobile app downloads can be crucial for giving you a starting
>   point for measuring how users interact with your application - we can
>   certainly help with that!
>
> There's two ways to approach this:
>
> The first way is through the first app open event. What we'll want to
>   do is trigger an event called App Install on the very first
>   application open. This is a proxy event for an install - it doesn't
>   *technically* fire when the user downloads the application, but rather, when the user opens the app for the first time. A lot of our
>   customers opt for this method for a couple of reasons, first, it's
>   more seamless from a technical perspective to set up, and second,
>   knowing the gap between users who install an application but never
>   open it is non-actionable knowledge. Say you had 100 users install the
>   application, but only 80 of them ever opened the app. There's nothing
>   one can do to change it so that next time those 20 open the app. Thus,
>   our customers opt for the App Install event on the first app open and
>   don't spend data points unnecessarily.
>
> The second option is to grab download data from the Google Play Store
>   directly
>   (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en).
>   If Google allows you to export that data, you could reformat it into a
>   Mixpanel event and utilize our import endpoint to send it to us:
>   https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/importing-events-older-than-31-days.
>   I think this format is harder, less realtime, and less actionable, so
>   I wouldn't recommend it - but in case you wanted the hard download
>   numbers from Google Play Store, Mixpanel can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The directions for tracking users on their first visit to your website or app are detailed at https://mixpanel.com/blog/2015/01/06/community-tip-tracking-first-time-users. In this you will find strategies for recording the first time a user interacts with your site or app -- you can apply these same concepts to track app installs.

If you have any additional questions please feel free to reach out to support@mixpanel.com -- Mixpanel checks this email throughout the day and can reply to you directly there with further info on this as needed!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you ryanseams, I followed your suggestion and I contacted directly support@mixpanel and I will paste the response as an answer because it adds relevant information